# I can not mount database exchange 2007

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

I have an Exchange 2007 database, when I try to mount it I get an error message: MapiExceptionJetDatabaseCorruption: Unable to mount database. (hr = 0x80004005, ec = -338)

I have checked if the database had an error with "Eseutil / mh" database.edb "but the status comes out as correct in:" Clean Shutdown "
Apparently everything is fine

How can I mount the database?

Comment: What caused the DB to dismount? Anything else in the event logs?
If you have good backup, I'd recommend you restore it from the backup and mount it again.

Answer (score 2):

This issue can be resolved in applying possible solution steps ways, As

**Note:** Your Database file gets corrupted or may occur due to DomainName\Exchange Servers group.

Before proceeding to the possible resolutions of this error, You can fix any kind of corruption issue via running Esetutil [commands](http://www.blog.edbtopst.org/how-to-repair-exchange-database-with-eseutil-and-isinteg-command-lines.html)

After that, you need to Setup /PrepareAD: **For Exchange Server 2007 Environment**

a) Start Exchange Server 2007 Help.
b) Click the Contents tab, expand Deployment, expand New Installation, expand Preparing to Deploy Exchange 2007, and then click How to Prepare Active Directory and Domains.

Not try to Add the Exchange Servers group to the **"Manage auditing and security log"** policy:

Follow the Steps mentioned below of [Blog](http://www.blog.edbtopst.org/how-to-repair-error-code-0x80004005-in-exchange-server-2010.html) to perform the task:

Open Domain Controller and log on in it by using the accounts having full administrator rights.

1) Open Administrator Tool and open Domain Controller Security Policy.
2) Now Go for local policies >> Security setting of Domain Controller and >> Select User Rights Assignment.
3) Open Manage Auditing and Security log >> Add Users or Group Type the Domain name exchange Servers in the box of User and group names.
4) Exit from the security settings of the Domain Controller >> wait until the Security Settings are applied.
5) Restart Information Store Services **(ISS)**

Answer (score 0):

Also check the consistency of your logs:

eseutil /ml "path of logs\E00"

if your database is showing in clean shutdown state then there is no need to run eseutil repair command.

Restore the database from updated backup. or you can also move ALL log files to another location and try to mount the database.